# Swap two String in java using without using third variable and without any inbuild API in Java

Tags: java, string, replace, substring, swap

Recently I have given an interview where they have asked me to swap two String without using any third variable and without using any String method like substring, replace or without using `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer`.

Eg:

```
String str1 = "hello";
String str2 = "morning";
```

output:

```
String str1 = "morning";
String str2 = "hello";
```

Comment: Just a comment, but that is a *really* weird interview question.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a trick that exploits assignment expressions (and evaluation order):

```
str2 = (new String[] { str1, (str1 = str2) })[0];
```

There surely can be many variations of that, but that does it.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some wired practicals I got one more wried solution using Ternary Operator.

**Solution:**
str1 = **str2** + ( (**str2**= **str1**) != **null** **?** ""**:**"");